# Dualshock4 and Joystick API [Linux]

Tags: linux, usb

I'm running Debian 12 on an X64 machine. I plugged in my Dualshock4 controller by USB and I can read from `/dev/input/js0` using the joystick API https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/joystick-api.txt.

Basically, I can read this struct from `/dev/input/js0`

```
struct js_event {
    __u32 time;     /* event timestamp in milliseconds */
    __s16 value;    /* value */
    __u8 type;      /* event type */
    __u8 number;    /* axis/button number */
};
```

My question is: who is writing this to `/dev/input/js0` so I can read it? Is there some module which handles the dualshock 4 input and writes it to `/dev/input/js0`?

Comment: Probably. Do `lsmod > before.txt` before you plug it in, then `lsmod > after.txt` after. Then `diff before.txt after.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you did not install any custom driver the joystick support on linux is typically covered by the `joydev` driver. It supports not only Sony DualShock 4 but a wide range of devices.

For detail about this driver check the kernel documentation:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/joydev/joystick.html

Comment: I do not see any references to dualshock on that page, nor in the joydev code.

Comment: Because it have only a general support for jaystick like devices and depends on basic linux device USB input interface. This driver does not support all Sony DualShock 4 features, like motion sensors or LEDs. There are planty of drivers made specificaly for DS4, e.g. this user space one is easy to handle: https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv